# Redirect a user to a specific view when authorization fails?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

I have the following code:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), Authorize(Roles = RoleKeys.Administrators)]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        User user = userRepository.GetUser(id);

        try
        {
            this.UpdateModel(user);

            userRepository.Save();

            return this.RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = user.UserId });
        }
        catch
        {
            this.ModelState.AddModelErrors(user.GetRuleViolations());

            return View(new UserFormViewModel(user));
        }
    }
```

If the currently logged in user is **not** in the Administrators role, it kicks them back to the login screen. The user is **already** logged in, they are just not authorize to perform the requested action.

Is there any way to have them redirected to a specific view, for example, AccessDenied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your own attribute:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization( AuthorizationContext filterContext )
    {
         base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
         if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
         {
             filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
             new RouteValueDictionary
             {
                 { "controller", "Login" },
                 { "action", "AccessDenied" }
             });
         }
    }
}
```

and use

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), MyAuthorize(Roles = RoleKeys.Administrators)]
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a filterContext.Cancel property?

Comment: I just removed the filterContext.Cancel and it all seems to work!